# What does this algorithm do?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

Got an exam tomorrow and one of the practice question asks what this algorithm written in pseudocode does.  Can anyone help?

```
Algorithm ???  
Input A: Array of Integers; n: Integer;  
Variables i, c: Integers;  

Begin 
    for i:=0 to n-1 do  
        c:=1;  
        while ((i+c)<n) and (A[i]<A[i+c]) do
           c:=c+1;
        od
        output(i,A[i],c-1);
    od
End
```

Comment: @bananamana that said, why don't you try to figure it out yourself?  Eg. try running it?

Comment: Care to elaborate on what the 3-argument output() function does?

Comment: @MK You can't run an algorithm unless you implement it first. This is just pseudo-code.

Comment: @marcog I think it is feasible to turn this into a working program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm takes an array of integers (sorted or unsorted) and outputs the number of items in the same array with an index higher than the current position **and** that are larger than the current index positions value.

For example

manually sorted array of ascending integers :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // stores an array of integers
    int [] myArray = {0,1,2,3};
    // assuming the length of array is n
    int n = myArray.length;
    // counter variables
    int i,c;
    // starting from array index 0 to the length of the array
    for(i=0;i<(n);i++){
        c = 1;
        while(((i+c)<n) && (myArray[i]<myArray[i+c])){
            c++;
        }
        System.out.println("index value..."+i+", myArray value..."+myArray[i]+", number of items in array with index greater than current with values greater than current..."+(c-1));
    }

}
```

would give the output

```
index value...0, myArray value...0, number of items in array with index greater than current with values greater than current...3
index value...1, myArray value...1, number of items in array with index greater than current with values greater than current...2
index value...2, myArray value...2, number of items in array with index greater than current with values greater than current...1
index value...3, myArray value...3, number of items in array with index greater than current with values greater than current...0
```

for a manually sorted array of descending integers :

```
 
int [] myArray = {10,9,8};
```

the output is :

```
index value...0, myArray value...10, number of items in array with index greater than current with values greater than current...0
index value...1, myArray value...9, number of items in array with index greater than current with values greater than current...0
index value...2, myArray value...8, number of items in array with index greater than current with values greater than current...0
```

for an array of integers all the same  :

```
int [] myArray = {1,1,1};
```

the output would be

```
index value...0, myArray value...1, number of items in array with index greater than current with values greater than current...0
index value...1, myArray value...1, number of items in array with index greater than current with values greater than current...0
index value...2, myArray value...1, number of items in array with index greater than current with values greater than current...0
```

Answer (score 1):

For each number in the array, this algorithm finds the count of numbers to its right that form a consecutive sequence of numbers greater than or equal to this number.

Comment: @MK Care to tell us what you believe it does then?

Comment: @MK Simple type, fixed. Please next time explain rather than down-vote. We are a community helping one another after all. :)

Comment: of course; I wouldn't do that on a real question, on a real mistake or if you had <1K rep :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's helping you help yourself and pass your exam:
What do you think it does?
If you pass it A = [1, 2, 3] and n = 3, what happens?
If you pass it A = [3, 2, 1, 0] and n = 3, what happens?
Could you code it up in Java/JavaScript/C#/Python/Erlang and see what happens yourself?